# Cannot red property 'getText' protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to do a loop into a loop and a get the `Cannot red property 'getText' of undefined` error.

Here is my code:

```
element.all(by.className('col-md-4 ng-scope')).then(function(content) {

  element.all(by.className('chart-small-titles dashboard-alignment ng-binding'))
  .then(function(items) {
      for(var i = 0; i<=content.length; i++) {
          items[i].getText().then(function(text) {
              expect(text).toBe(arrayTitle[i]);
          });
      }
  });

  element.all(by.className('mf-btn-invisible col-md-12 ng-scope'))
  .then(function(itemsText) {
      for(var i=0; i<=content.length; i++) {
          for(var x = 0; x<=arrayContent.length; x++) {
              itemsText[i].getText().then(function(textContent) {
                  expect(textContent).toBe(arrayContent[x]);
              });
          }
      }
  });
});
```

I am using the `.then` in the `.getText()` so i don't know what happens.

Comment: Check `items[i]` the `i` not exceed index range, because you used `i<=content.length`.  Same check on `itemsText[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem now is you wrote 30 lines of code and you debug all of them at once. There maybe 1000 on possible issues. For this reason noone will help you, because I don't want to waste my time and make blind guesses myself. But if you reorgonize your code so you can debug them 1 by 1 line, then every line may have only a few issues.

With that said, stop using callbacks, I can see you don't completely understand what they do. Instead start using `async/await`. See how easy it is... Your code from question will look like this

```
// define elementFinders
let content = element.all(by.className('col-md-4 ng-scope'));
let items = element.all(by.className('chart-small-titles dashboard-alignment ng-binding'));
let itemsText = element.all(by.className('mf-btn-invisible col-md-12 ng-scope'));

// get element quantity
let contentCount = await content.count();
let itemsTextCount = await itemsText.count();

// iterate
for(var i = 0; i<contentCount; i++) {
    // get text
    let text = await items.get(i).getText();
    // assert
    expect(text).toBe(arrayTitle[i]);
}

// iterate
for(var i=0; i<contentCount; i++) {
    for(var x = 0; x<itemsTextCount; x++) {
        // get text
        let text = await itemsText.get(i).getText();
        // assert
        expect(text).toBe(arrayContent[x]);
    }
}
```

This way you can `console.log` any variable and see where your code breaks

Comment: there was one correction I made. It's possible that the code already works since I fixed a list of issues. Try that and let me know what you see and if you have problems understanding how the code works