# Recursive function Error getting text from an element

Tags: javascript, protractor

im trying to do a recursive function like this:

```
function recurse(index, items) {
    if(index<items.length) {
        items[index].getText().then(function(itemtext) {
            items[index].click().then(function() { 
                browser.params.utils.waitForElement('disappear', browser.params.constants.GENERALPATHS.ALERTS_AND_COLLISIONS.SPINNER, waitLongTime, 'present').then(function() {
                    element.all(by.className('ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-disable-selection ui-grid-coluiGrid-00YV darkness-cell-row')).then(function(itemtotext) {
                        itemtotext[0].getText().then(function(text) {
                            expect(itemtext).toBe(text);
                            browser.element(by.className('glyphicon glyphicon-remove')).click().then(function() {
                                browser.params.utils.waitForElement('disappear', browser.params.constants.GENERALPATHS.ALERTS_AND_COLLISIONS.SPINNER, waitLongTime, 'present');
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });                       
            });
        });
        recurse(index+1,items);
    } else {

    }
}
```

I got the error in the second getText(): `Cannot read property 'getText' of undefined` so i don't know why I got this error.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: A perfect example of `callback hell`. Use `async-await` it will be a hell lot easier to debug and understand the code.

Comment: This error means `items[index]` does not reference a valid element.

Comment: Ther is not the problem, is in the second getText() @DNT

Comment: first, what I said here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61976699/9150146 is still valid in this question. Don't overcomplecate your code in the first place. Second, how do you want to be helped if you don't respond on answers (in previous questions)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unnecessary nested `then()` to make code more readable.
Recommend to use `await/async`

```
function resurse(index, items) {
  class_name = 'ui-grid-cell ng-scope ui-grid-disable-selection ' + 
               'ui-grid-coluiGrid-00YV darkness-cell-row';

  if (index < items.length) {
    itemtext = items[index].getText();
    items[index].click();
    browser.params.utils.waitForElement(
      'disappear', 
      browser.params.constants.GENERALPATHS.ALERTS_AND_COLLISIONS.SPINNER, 
      waitLongTime, 
      'present'
    );
    itemtotext = element.all(by.className(class_name)).first().getText();

    promise.all([itemtext, itemtotext]).then(function(values){
      expct(values[0]).toEqual(values[1])
    });

    element(by.className('glyphicon glyphicon-remove')).click();

    browser.params.utils.waitForElement(
      'disappear', 
      browser.params.constants.GENERALPATHS.ALERTS_AND_COLLISIONS.SPINNER, 
      waitLongTime, 'present'
    );

    browser.getTitle().then(function(){
       recurse(index + 1, items);
    });

  }
}
```