# How promises are getting resolved in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have a doubt, it is written that : Finding web elements is asynchronous, whether it’s a single element or a collection, so the result is a promise. So if this is the case , the how below code snippet is working:

```
describe('the contact list', () => {
 it('with filter: should find existing ' +
 'contact "Craig Service"', () => {
   let tbody = element(by.tagName('tbody'));
   let trs = tbody.all(by.tagName('tr'));
   let craigService = trs.filter(elem => {
   return elem.all(by.tagName('td')).get(1).getText()
     .then(text => {
       return text === 'Craig Service';
     });
   });
```

Isn't trs needs to be resolved using then().. ,before we are moving to the next line where we are using filter function( craigService)?
If that is being handled by Protractor promise -manager, can we use the same strategy for getting the text of an element using gettext()..and later using it without using then()..?

Comment: No, you can't use the text without waiting for it. Some of the lines in your code above can be explained by the process 'lazy evaluation' -- even though they're asynchronous, you can do operations on them without waiting as long as those operations don't immediately need to know the actual values of the elements. Doing stuff with the text value, on the other hand, isn't really like that....

Comment: Hi, thanks. Can you please help me in getting some operations which comes under 'lazy evaluation' and those which we need to wait. Any docs or link can be useful

Comment: I guess every method that creates a new protactor object is deferred and executed asynchronously, but all methods that would return a plain value (such as `getText`) do return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If that is being handled by Protractor promise -manager

Protractor promise manager (AKA SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER) [is removed](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2969) starting from protractor 6. So forget about it

> Finding web elements is asynchronous

In my own words, finding web elements with a purpose of manipulating with it (`click()`, `getText()` etc) is asynchronous and thus returns a Promise, which need to be resolved. However what you have on this line

```
let trs = tbody.all(by.tagName('tr'));
```

is just an elementArrayFinder declaration. It doesn't return promise, and thus it has a synchronous nature. So you can declare this element, long time before you even open a browser

If you intend to work with protractor a lot, bookmark this [protractor API](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder) page. On this page, they say what every command returns. If that does not have `promise.Promise` or something like that, it doesn't need to be resolved (exception is `browser.get` which I happen to know is a promise too, but they don't mention that)

Answering your quesion

> Isn't `trs` needs to be resolved

As per protractor page `element()` doesn't return a Promise, as well as `element.all()` so NO, they don't need to be resolved

Now when you know how to find out if you work with promises or not, lets talk how to resolve Promises

1. Good old `.then()` syntax (not really good, but old indeed)

```
element(by.css('.class')).getText().then(function(text){
  console.log(text)
})
```

Now when you know this method, erase that from your memory. This is extra information which will make your code not readable and extremely hard to debug. Just look at this [Promise Hell](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/how-to-get-out-of-promise-hell-8c20e0ab0513) and you'll understand what I'm talking about

2. `async/await`
   This is as good as copy/paste on your computer. God bless creators of both, I can't imagine my life without them. So the same code from #1 now looks like this

```
let text = await element(by.css('.class')).getText();
console.log(text)
```

Doesn't it make a lot more sense when you look at the snippet? For another example see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952787/cannot-red-property-gettext-protractor/61976699#61976699). Basically `await` says to javascript 'stop, resolve promise, return it's value'

To summarize, if you resolve your snippet's promises with `async/await` you'll get

```
describe('the contact list', () => {
  it('with filter: should find existing contact "Craig Service"', async () => { // pay attention to this async
    let tbody = element(by.tagName('tbody'));
    let trs = tbody.all(by.tagName('tr'));
    let craigService = await trs.filter(async elem => { // async again
      let text = await elem.all(by.tagName('td')).get(1).getText()
      return text === 'Craig Service'
    });
```

Comment: That is an awesome explanation. Thanks and lot ;)